# Using POV-Ray installed via the APT

Tags: apt, povray

I installed POV-Ray by running `sudo apt-get install povray` but now whenever I run:

```
povray Jmol.pov.ini
```

I get the error:

```
povray: cannot open the user configuration file /home/fusion809/.povray/3.7/povray.conf: No such file or directory

Problem with option setting
povray /home/fusion809/Chem Structures/Crystal structures/Jmol.pov.ini
Failed to parse command-line option
```

where Jmol.pov.ini is the ini file, that is in the same directory as its corresponding pov file, and both were produced by Jmol. I feared that I may have foolishly removed my .povray directory (as the directory doesn't exist at the location specified in this error message) so I reinstalled povray by running:

```
sudo apt-get install povray --reinstall
```

But unfortunately the .povray directory still doesn't exist and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered the solution by running `dpkg -L povray` which told me where all POV-Ray-associated files were and I found the missing `povray.conf` file was (`/etc/povray/3.7/`) so I ran this from the terminal (from my home directory):

```
ln -s /etc/povray/ .povray
```

which created a virtual link between the directories so that when POV-Ray went looking in the `/home/fusion809/.povray/3.7/` directory it found what it was looking for.