# Problems with running POVray in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: povray

I installed PoVRay 3.7 by running `sudo apt-get install povray`, but now when I try to run with a postscript file as the input I get the following  error:

```
povray: cannot open the user configuration file /root/.povray/3.7/povray.conf: No such file or directory
```

I tried the steps suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628496/using-pov-ray-installed-via-the-apt), but that did not help.

If anyone could provide a solution, it would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, PovRay will not render a postscript file, only Scene Description Language files (.pov) or batch files (.ini). Are you mixing PovRay up with GhostScript?

2nd, your instance is looking for `/root/.povray/3.7/povray.conf` while the answered question was looking for `/home/fusion809/.povray/3.7/povray.conf`.

So you should run that `ln -s /etc/povray/ .povray` from your `/root` directory.